# Why don't CSS transitions work on page load?

Tags: javascript, css, transition

It seems that changing CSS properties with JavaScript doesn't work with transitions when executing the JavaScript code on page load.

Here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <style>
    div {
      background: red;
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div />
  <script>
    var div = document.querySelector("div");

    // the following doesn't work as intended
    div.style.marginTop = "100px";

    // the following works fine
    /*setTimeout(() => (
    div.style.marginTop = "100px"
    ), 0);*/
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This can be resolved by encapsulating the changes to be made in a call to `setTimeout()`, even with `0` as second argument.

Can someone explain me this behaviour?

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Xufox please explain me how my codepen demonstration isn't a minimal, complete, and verifiable example.

Comment: @gentilpapillon Code samples should be _within_ the question, not as an external resource link, and the reason is that when that link dies, so does the value of the question and its answers.

Comment: @LGSon thank you for your answer, I edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaScript code is run before the first frame. And because the first frame being rendered already has the changed values no transition is starting.

`setTimeout(...,0)` works because setTimeout creates a callback and waits until the main thread is free, which is after the rendering process.

Comment: Makes sense. And how comes the setTimeout() with a second argument value of `0` resolves the problem?

Comment: `setTimeout` creates a callback and waits until the main thread is free, which is after the  rendering process

Comment: I get it fully now. Would you please edit your answer to add this part explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping your JS in a `window.onload` function which it is fired **after** the entire page loads, including its content (images, css, scripts, etc...) will fix this.

```js
window.onload = function () {
    var div = document.querySelector("div");

    // the following doesn't use the transition
    div.style.marginTop = "100px";

    // the following uses the transition
    /*setTimeout(() => (
      div.style.marginTop = "100px"
    ), 0);*/
};
```

```css
div {
  background: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div />
```